# How to resolve .zshenv. command not found pyenv?

Tags: pyenv

I have pyenv installed and my .zshenv looks like the following :

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME"/.pyenv
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT"/bin:"$PATH"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

When I open a new terminal it gives me the following error:

**.zshenv. command not found: : pyenv**

Comment: Hopefully you should be able to find your answer here - https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/233#issuecomment-490677591

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fix in the github issue link didn't work for me.

The problem was that `pyenv` wasn't on the path at the time of running `pyenv init`.

I add `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:"$PATH"` to my .zshenv before calling `pyenv init`.

Answer (score 1):

this is my fix, it was a simple order of operation of the zsh; [Order of reading startup files in zsh](https://ss64.com/osx/syntax-profile.html):
.zshenv → .zprofile → .zshrc → .zlogin

so now my .zshenv and .zprofile look like this:

```
eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"
export PYENV_ROOT="$/usr/local/bin/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

[also i needed to create a .zprofile and .zshenv](https://www.insightsjava.com/2022/01/how-to-create-bash-profile-on-mac.html) 
(do the same instrustions for zprofile just swap zshenv)